# Azure Release Pipeline Authentication Required

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have some onsite servers that we deploy to with Azure DevOps release pipelines. We have been using these release pipelines for several months with no issues. Today, we started getting an authentication error while downloading the artifact for the project.

The nodes in the deployment group show online, the build pipeline is successful, yet it shows the error below when we try to deploy anything. We even tried completely reconfiguring the Azure agent on each server for one of our applications to ensure that some access tokens hadn't expired or something, but it still gives the error below. There is no elaboration on what the error is beyond just "Authentication required". Googling has been fruitless, as well. What could cause an authentication error at this "Download artifact" stage?

Ticket submitted to Microsoft, other than a suggestion to skip downloading the artifact (which didn't work) nothing has been suggested.

[image: Authentication Required Error]

**Update:** The deployment works on my home PC and my local PC at work, so the issue seems to be limited to our web servers. Here is the log with System.Debug enabled. Doesn't seem to be anything helpful, but I may have missed something.

```
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1399175Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Download artifact - _myproject - _myproject'
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1439702Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1445026Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1483132Z ##[debug]=> True
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1491321Z ##[debug]Result: True
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1532198Z ##[section]Starting: Download artifact - _myproject - _myproject
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1961448Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1961906Z Task         : Download pipeline artifact
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1962269Z Description  : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1962470Z Version      : 1.2.5
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1962782Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1963334Z Help         : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
2021-10-18T20:44:18.1963578Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-18T20:44:18.4789044Z Download from the specified build: #2263
2021-10-18T20:44:18.4791191Z Download artifact to: D:\azagent\myproject\_work\r1\a/_myproject/_myproject
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8728223Z Verbose, [CreateDedupManifestClientAsync] Try 1/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:01. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8729052Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8729972Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8730690Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8731302Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8731978Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8732555Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8733094Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8733663Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8734201Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8734958Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8735519Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8736036Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8736631Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8737255Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8738854Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8739525Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8739923Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8740372Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Blob.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateDedupManifestClientAsync>b__0()
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8740847Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8741215Z Verbose, Details:
2021-10-18T20:44:18.8741600Z No LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9351139Z Verbose, [CreateDedupManifestClientAsync] Try 2/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:02.0448362. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9352093Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9352734Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9353423Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9354090Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9354714Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9355275Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9355818Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9356323Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9356861Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9357434Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9358243Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9358773Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9359406Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9360043Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9361138Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9361660Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9362070Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9362498Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Blob.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateDedupManifestClientAsync>b__0()
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9363016Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9363388Z Verbose, Details:
2021-10-18T20:44:19.9363777Z No LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0672040Z Verbose, [CreateDedupManifestClientAsync] Try 3/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:04.3215402. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0675355Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0677878Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0679896Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0681705Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0683412Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0685178Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0687056Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0688698Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0690182Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0691833Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0694193Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0695575Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0697636Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0699432Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0700506Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0701793Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0702700Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0703611Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Blob.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateDedupManifestClientAsync>b__0()
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0704534Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0705338Z Verbose, Details:
2021-10-18T20:44:22.0706254Z No LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4694926Z Verbose, [CreateDedupManifestClientAsync] Try 4/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:07.4023007. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4696834Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4697595Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4698258Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4698938Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4699631Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4700281Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4700879Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4701470Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4702073Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4702761Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4703411Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4704322Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4705006Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4705725Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4706315Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4706760Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4707247Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4707735Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Blob.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateDedupManifestClientAsync>b__0()
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4708278Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4708663Z Verbose, Details:
2021-10-18T20:44:26.4709048Z No LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9617890Z Verbose, [CreateDedupManifestClientAsync] Try 5/5, retryable exception caught. Retrying in 00:00:13.8309011. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9619853Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9620854Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9622449Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9624109Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9624968Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9626162Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9628510Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9629698Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9630828Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9632166Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9633218Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9634309Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9636019Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9636772Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9637302Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9637709Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9638034Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9639150Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Blob.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateDedupManifestClientAsync>b__0()
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9639655Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9639980Z Verbose, Details:
2021-10-18T20:44:33.9640279Z No LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8770587Z Verbose, [CreateDedupManifestClientAsync] Try 6/5, retryable exception caught, but retries have been exhausted. Throwing. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8771374Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8771952Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8772597Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8773209Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8773846Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8774406Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8774928Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8775437Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8775959Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8776553Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnectionAsync(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8777139Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8777674Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8778529Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8779188Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8779688Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8780073Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8780389Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8780800Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Blob.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateDedupManifestClientAsync>b__0()
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8781330Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8781651Z Verbose, Details:
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8781946Z No LastRequestResponse on exception VssServiceResponseException: Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8839489Z ##[error]Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8847397Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Authentication Required
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8855146Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
2021-10-18T20:44:47.8862951Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at...
```

Comment: Have you tried running the pipeline with diagnostics enabled? Doing this and posting the log may help? When you reconfigured the Azure Agent I'm assuming you generated and used new PATs?

Comment: @TheWinterCoder I attached a log from when we discovered we could use System.Debug...doesn't seem to be much there that's helpful. However, we did notice that this works on different PCs, so it seems to be limited to these servers.

Comment: @SausageBuscuit Were any software updates installed on the release agents recently?

Comment: Are you using a domain account or a PAT to register the deployment group.  The credentials or PAT are all still valid and not expired?

Comment: I'm not sure what version it was on initially because another user removed and re-added the agent, but we are on the latest version now (2.194.0). We are using a PAT to register the deployment group.

Comment: Would it be possible to attach a screenshot showing how the Download artifact step is configured?

Comment: And can you compare the agent versions on your work/home PC where this works to the agent version on the servers where this is failing? Are they all on the same version, or are the ones that are working on older versions?

Comment: One more thought  -> Could you try manually accessing the connectionData API at https://dev.azure.com/[organization_name]/_apis/connectionData in powershell or web browser from one of the servers that is having this error? This api is what the pipeline is failing to connect to, so if there is a proxy auth issue then this should fail and you might get a more detailed error message.

Comment: @Brenton +1, your answer helped get me pointed in the right direction. Oddly enough, when I went to dev.azure.com/{my_org} directly, it gave me the proxy login prompt which made me think proxy. However, when I went to the api site that you described and instead it told me that dev.azure.com was missing from trusted sites on the server. Once I added it here, we have not had any issues. I am still unsure why the main site did not do this, but I think it may be because it's redirecting elsewhere (such as login.microsoft.com), which was in our list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the cause was embarrassingly simple. Some sort of policy or cleanup process removed dev.azure.com from the list of trusted sites from our servers. Once I added it back to this, it seems to work.